# Getting better OCR results

Tags: python, jupyter, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to get data from screenshots of an ICU ventilator and I already wrote a somehow functional notebook, seperating the boxes in the images and cleaning them up. Below is an example of how the images look after preprocessing and the output, created by tesseract.

> Output: {'date': '2020-08-11\n\x0c', 'time': '09:23:06\n\x0c',
> 'Ppeak': '\x0c', 'Pmittel': '77\n\x0c', 'PEEP': '5.0\n\x0c', 'VTi':
> '430\n\x0c', 'VTe': '434\n\x0c', 'fTotal': '\x0c', 'Rinsp': '\x0c',
> 'Rexsp': '\x0c', 'Cstat': '47.2\n\x0c', 'RCinsp': '\x0c', 'RCexsp':
> '\x0c', 'O2%': '\x0c'}

Generated by this:

```
for entry in data_map1:
        # seperate the matching part of the image
        rec = _improveImage(img[data_map1[entry][2] : data_map1[entry][3], data_map1[entry][0] : data_map1[entry][1]])
        # Recognise the image
        data[entry] = pytesseract.image_to_string(rec, lang='eng')
```

Removing "\x0c" and "\n" is not the problem, but I really wonder why some of the values aren't recognised at all, while some other ones are perfect. Do I need to improve my preprocessing? Or some settings in tesseract?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Processed Images]

Comment: I've noticed Tesseract isn't very good with small images. Try resampling your images up to "scan-like" resolutions, maybe 5x from your current sizes?

Comment: as @AKX mentioned `Tesseract` may have problem with too small and too big text. See tesseract documentation: [ImproveQuality](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)

Comment: maybe you should try [Template Matching in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) but it need to detect every digit separatelly. This method is also used by `PyAutoGUI` to detect elements/buttons on screen to click buttons.

Comment: or maybe you should train own model to detect digist - one of many example with popular [MNIST Handwritten Digits](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-scratch-for-mnist-handwritten-digit-classification/)